# Grouping together similar sentence strings in a csv file

Tags: python, string, csv, pandas, fuzzy-comparison

I'm currently working on a project in Python that relies on taking in a csv file. The csv file contains over several thousand random sentences with some similarity between certain ones. The purpose of my code is to identify which sentences are of a kind and refer to the same thing context wise.

For example, all sentences that refer to Gmail such as:

```
Gmail login
Gmail account login
Gmail account register
```

refer to the same context but can be very far from each other in the input file, nested among unrelated sentences referring to different contexts. My method I have been using so far is to:

1. Sort each word in a sentence alphabetically and to lowercase such as:

   account gmail login
2. Make their original index in the file its own column, sort the sentences alphabetically in the csv file and then load them into a pandas dataframe
3. Iterte through the dataframe and compare sentences to each other. This is done using [FuzzyWuzzy's](http://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/) token_set_ratio method to identify terms that are of a match to each other (equality == 100), words that are similar are grouped together then written to a file.
4. When the dataframe has been iterated through, we then loop through it again and match the index we made into its own column to the corresponding row in the input file to return the original sentence.

This approach has been promising but it is suffering from bad matches and sentences not being of the same context ending up in the same group. Is there a better method available that does what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to implement document similarity analysis, coming from the text analysis/mining field.

In your case, you seem to have documents (lines) of words that are standardized. You can then perform comparison of documents, without comparing words by trigram similarities of Levenstein distance.

Basically, use an [inverted file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) for storing the terms, and perform [cosine similarity in the vector model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model) is a simple and efficient method for detect document similarities.

Using some other techniques, or [distance/similarity scores](https://dataaspirant.com/2015/04/11/five-most-popular-similarity-measures-implementation-in-python/), allows to refine the results.

EDIT: A python module, [`gensim`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gensim), implements the vector space model and seems to be well-featured.
[NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) is a well-known framework for natural language analysis, and provide tons of feature for that type of work.